# Custom TextInputLayout - inner editText is null

Tags: android

I want to create custom class which extends `TextInputLayout` and have sort of an access into its inner `EditText`, so I can set focus listener on it. Based on focus state and text in the `EditText` the error shows in `TextInputLayout`. Below is my current simple code where edit text is null. How can I achieve so have custom `TextInputLayout` that can communicate with its inner `EditText` ?

```
class CustomTextInputLayout : TextInputLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    init {
            Log.e("_TEST", this.editText?.toString() ?: "null") // gives null
            editText?.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (hasfocus.not()) {
                    val textToCheck = editText?.text.toString()
                    this.error = someValidationFunction(textToCheck)
                }

            }
    }
}
```

```xml
<com.app.utility.CustomTextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.app.utility.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891219/custom-textinputlayout-android

Comment: dont think its the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `editText` isn't initialized in `init` method yet. First, the parent will be laid out then the child. 
Please, check this method

```
onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Views lifecycle is very important if you want to create custom views or viewgroups.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html